# Reading lines in pdf file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've got pdf file that looks like it:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg6tg.png)

It would be easy if each word of first line would have child in the next one. But sometimes the parents are empty below. I can get whole text from pdf and find those two lines. But if there is break in third column then reading the whole text I lose information if the third word was in forth column or third column. I hope I've made it clear, but I would appreciate idea how to read those two lines and connecting them, considering that not each parent has child in next line.

Comment: maybe need use some OCR sdk. cause the content of many pdf files is in the form of pictures

Comment: You can override text stripper methods to retrieve not only text but also its coordinates. That should allow you to recognize those columns.

Comment: Also consider using various heuristics to determine ( say with pattern length / regex ) to determine which datum is which